# Multiple y plots on same logarithmic scale for the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot 3 curves using the `semilogx` matlab function and add a fourth line to an additional y axis on the right. All of them should be plotted on the same logarithmic scale for the x-axis. The following code indicates the derived error; the x-axis is incorrect. The figure has to have a single x-axis mode of ticks, the logarithm one. How could this be fixed?

Plus, how can I add a legend for these 4 curves?

```
close all, clc
figure, semilogx([1:100:1000],[rand(1,10)],'bo-'), 
xlabel('xlabel'),ylabel('ylabel'), hold on; 
semilogx([1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)], 'ro-'), hold on,
semilogx([1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)], 'ko-'), hold off
legend('1','2','3','Location','Best')

ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color' , 'none',...
           'YColor', 'm');
linkaxes([ax1 ax2 ], 'x')

x4 = [1:100:1000];
y4 = [rand(1,10)*2];
line(x4, y4, 'color', 'm', 'Marker','x','LineStyle',':', 'parent',ax1)
ylabel('y2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) function to plot two of your lines, one on the right and one on the left. You can then `hold on` and plot the remaining lines using `semilogx`.

```
plotyy([1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)], [1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)]*2, @semilogx);
hold on;
semilogx([1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)], 'ro-');
semilogx([1:100:1000], [rand(1,10)], 'mo-');
hold off;
legend('Line1','Line2','Line3','Line4','Location','Northwest')
```

[image]